# How to pass a custom parameter to facebook login?

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I have a static website without any server side languages.

Is it possible to pass some custom values whenever a user tries to login then get the data back when the user successfully signed in and comes back to my website from facebook?

I've read about signed_request, but that requires PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're essentially asking if Facebook will store data for you.

Unfortunately, the answer is no.  You need some kind of mechanism on your server that can match a Facebook user to the data you need stored.

You could use local storage, but that's obviously local to the browser and prone to tampering.

Comment: I think I don't need to save it anymore. It looks like JS SDK for the facebook doesn't actually refresh the page I'm on. Thank you for the input.